# Filtering Google Sheet with Merged-Celled Headers & Extract Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have trouble filtering and getting the right data with my Google Sheet due to merged-celled headers. I can't use the basic filtering tool. I think there's a way to filter it using functions such as QUERY and Array but I just don't know the right formula. I've been watching Youtube tutorials and I still haven't figured it out yet.

If you had this spreadsheet, and you want to see only the list of members who has missing payments let's say for the month of April. How would you filter it? Is it possible?
[image]

Also, I want too auto extract all received reimbursement amount for all the completed sessions of the members in the list. This reimbursement amount can be found in two separate tab sheets RR1 and RR2. In sheets RR1 and RR2Is there's only specific member ID and month, no name, and it's put in 1 cell. Is it possible to auto-extract the corresponding total reimbursement amount and populate it in the Received Reimbursement column of the main sheet Tracker? What function and formula would you use?

[image]

I hope this all makes sense. Thank you so much for assistance.

Googlesheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q_B5Cj_vv9Jzcm9aLAY_gNKHaaoEEUrJ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115853268191643677574&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Try this formula in **`Cell_Q3`** for **April** month. For the other months just copy the **`Q3 Cell with formula`** & paste it in `H3, K3, N3, T3...` for their respective months to populate*

```js
=map($A3:$A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,let(x,{'RR1'!$A:$A;'RR2'!$A:$A},y,{'RR1'!$B:$B;'RR2'!$B:$B},ifna(sum(filter(y,--regexextract(x,"\d+$")=Σ,regexmatch(x,"^(?:ASH|Renew) "&P1&" 2023"))))))))
```

[image]

- *Regarding filtering the data; you can skip the first row (merged cells) and apply from the second row to the bottom*

Comment: You're awesome. The formula makes my head hurts. So I pasted it on cell Q3 for April and verified if the amount that populates matches the what's in RR1 and RR2 - they did match. However, when I pasted the formula to other cells, it gives me "#REF", so I figured to change the part where "&P1&" with the G1 for January, J1 for February, and so on. I checked the populated amount and they looked correct. Did I do it right? You're a genius!

Comment: yes the alternative is to *manually* change `P1` in the formula to `G1, J1, M1...`and so on. However I've pre-adjusted the formula in such a way that once you've had the above formula in `Q3` for *April*, you can then copy paste *Q3* into `H3, K3, N3...` without issues OR manually adjusting anything. Since I've no idea on how you implemented this process for it to throw *#REF* error, cant really comment on that. Cool

Comment: Hello! Happy Thanksgiving! Hope you're enjoying your holiday. Your formula really help me cut the time in doing my report. However, it seems to be not working anymore. The Member ID of the people in the sheet has changed into a combination of letters and numbers(ex: 308350GR10) . Perhaps it's the reason the formula is not working anymore? My guess is that the formula only works on numerical values. What should I change in the formula so that it can search for ID or value that has letters and numbers and do the math? Hope to hear back from you. Thank you so much!